# Java/scala regex won't match special characters denoted by caret

Tags: regex, scala

I have a regex with all legal character carefully chosen and escaped, however it still fail to capture any illegal characters, namely `:$&` etc:

```
val result = "http://example.com?re#k2$si".replaceAll("""[^0-9a-zA-Z!-_\.\*'\(\)]+""","/")
assert(url === "http/example.com/re/k2/si")
```

but the result is:

> TestFailedException: "http[://example.com?re#k2$]si" did not equal "http[/example.com/re/k2/]si"

what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a character class, you need to escape a literal `-` by putting it at the end or beginning or the class; otherwise it will create a charater range.

You forgot to do so for `!-_`, thus creating a large range from ascii code 33 to 95, and now the `:/?$` are caught in the negated character class as well.

Also, notice that [metacharacters aren't the same inside a character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and you can remove some useless escapes.

Try with:

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z!_.*'()-]+
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, you are right, the 12 metacharacters are only a small part of special char that needs to be handled differently. This fix the problem immediately